# Load Error when requiring taglib-ruby

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks, require, taglib, taglib-ruby

I'm trying to use the Ruby wrapper gem for Taglib to play around with ID3 Tags in a practice program. I'm getting Load Errors regarding the requiring of the taglib ruby gem.

I've installed the gem into my project via RubyGems and am simply requiring the gem as stated in a number of posts:

```
require 'taglib'
```

These are the software versions I'm working with:

- ruby 2.0.0p481
- taglib-ruby (0.7.1)
- taglib-1.9.1

I'm on a Mac with Mavericks 10.9.5, using RubyMine as my IDE. 
I'm not sure if my installation is correct for taglib (the original, not the Ruby wrapper). I used Homebrew to download the .tar.gz file and then unzipped this. The Taglib 1.10 folder is sitting in my local downloads folder - should this be placed somewhere else?

As mentioned, I'm requiring 'taglib' at the top of my .rb file. The error I'm getting when trying to run this file is:

```
'require': cannot load such file -- taglib (LoadError)
```

I'm pretty new to Ruby and SO so anything else I need to clarify, please ask. Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you install Ruby? How did you install the gem?  It looks like you haven't installed the gem, just downloaded it  The require simply isn't pointing to where the file needs to be loaded from.  I am not familiar with the gem, but usually installing the gems using `gem install <gemname>` will place the gems in the "correct" location for your installation.  Depending on how your Ruby is installed, you may need to use `sudo`.

Comment: I installed Ruby with rvm, and have RubyMotion working with my default Ruby version 2.0.0p481. I installed taglib using Homebrew, and then installed taglib-ruby using the 'gem install tagliib-ruby' command from within my program directory. Gem list from this directory shows: taglib-ruby (0.7.1)

Answer (score 1):

When you require a file, the file must be either in your `$LOAD_PATH` variable for Ruby, or explicitly indicated in the require string.

The error that you posted is specific to this.  The require command leaves off the extension, as it will load other types of files other than Ruby if they are available.  See the documentation on the `require` method for more information.

If you have installed the library in `~/my_projects/music_analyzer/taglib_unzip_folder` then you can use `require '~/my_projects/music_analyzer/taglib_unsip_folder/taglib` and the error messages should change.

If you have installed the gem, and are using rvm, you should not use `sudo`, but should use `gem install taglib-ruby`

And in this case you would not need to specify the folder name, as the path would be included in Ruby's load path.

If you are using an IDE, and that IDE is not using the same environment, then you will end up with load problems, as your installation and the IDE's environment may not be identical.

Instead of using the IDE, you can test these things out right at the terminal, using irb.

```
>> require 'taglib'
=> true
```

Comment: Thanks vgoff, really helpful answer that's well written for a new learner. It helped a lot in working this out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On your Mac Terminal try to type `gem list`. This should give you the list of installed gem. If the gem is not showing up, type `gem install "gem-name"` to install it.

Comment: Yeah, gem list shows taglib-ruby (0.7.1) as successfully installed in the project folder. I don't know why the require isn't picking this up. I'm wondering is the problem something to do with my installation of the taglib library (written in C++) that's not allowing the taglib-ruby wrapper gem to work. Should the taglib (the C++ one) be showing up in my gem list (it's not) or be installed somewhere relevant, or is there some pointing to this library that I must do to get taglib-ruby to work? Thanks

Comment: I should note that I've installed, removed and reinstalled the taglib API. My installation of it is nothing more than: 'brew install taglib' which downloaded a .tar.gz file. I unzipped this file from within my downloads folder and that's as much as I've done on the taglib (C++) part.

Comment: According to the documentation, the steps to follows are: install taglib with brew: `brew install taglib` and then install the gem `gem install taglib-gem`